# AWS Bitnami Multisite instance issue WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed Bitnami Multisite on my AWS instance. I have the following issues.

Once installed, i tried to access it via the public IP provided by AWS it would not load up but i can access my site and dashboard via public DNS ie. ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

I created 3 separate site within the app using subdomain (the only option available). I cannot access neither the dashboard nor the sub-site itself either by public IP or Public DNS.

Moving forward, in continuation to the above, since I will be providing A records to my domain, I associated an EIP to the same multisite instance. Same issue happened with my app but this time could not access it neither by IP or DNS. Dissociating the EIP didn't help and it ended up trashing my installation as I cant access it anymore.

My Questions
How can I access via public IP or IP so i can assign that to my A Records of the domain?

I am developing the website so is possible i can asses all my sub domains via ip or dns before pushing it live on the domain.

How will I access my subdomains or how can I change the sub domains to sub directory?
How can I associate an EIP to my app?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an AWS user but I know Azure etc use internal and external IP routing. So your can't view a website with an internal IP without certain technical aspects in place. You'd not use an internal IP for a public facing website. Therefore, I'd suggest looking for the external IP and try that.

Comment: Also, this doesn't really look like its a WordPress related issue, so that tag should probably be removed.